# WhatsApp data transfer from expired SIM card to new SIM card

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, sim-card, data-transfer

My old SIM card number has expired and is no longer active on my mobile network. How do I recover my WhatsApp account chat history from this inactive SIM card number since it can no longer receive the call or message that sends the WhatsApp confirmation code to my cell phone in order to activate the WhatsApp account to my old mobile number?

I have tried to purchase a new SIM card in order to reactivate the expired mobile number but was told by my network providers that I can no longer use that number as it is no longer registered to the network. My best bet would be to try to recover my contacts from my Google account backups. But there's no guarantee that I can recover my chat history from that expired number.

I would like to migrate my WhatsApp chat history from this old SIM card number to a new SIM card number to which I have already installed WhatsApp.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp stores a backup of every day into your internal memory. If you register in WhatsApp with the new SIM, it will still allow you to restore the messages of the previous chat. No matter what number you had.

Try re-registering with your new number and when it asks you for restoring back, allow it to.

Comment: The same thing happened to me. Are u sure that, if we register the new sim with watsapp then also we will get the option to restore. Is this 100%sure . Otherwise we can no longer use the old chat noo..

Comment: i tried this, none of the backups worked. My sim card expired and i had to change both my no and phone. I changed my whatsapp no on the old phone first then transferred to the new phone and the transfer encountered errors. I then tried backups but none of them from google or local worked. The backups are encrypted with the old phone no so unless you can get whatsapp to work with a different no without the sim you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Of course, you must copy the old folder WhatsApp to the new phone so that WhatsApp sees that the folder containing the database is read by WhatsApp.